# Determining the distribution of Q

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_9$ denote a sample. Assume that $X_i \sim N(4\theta, \theta^2)$ for $i = 1,...,9$ with an unknown $\theta > 0$. We want to find the confidence interval for $\theta$.

a) Find the distribution of
$$ Q = \frac{3\bar{X}}{\theta} - 12 $$
where $\bar{X} = \displaystyle{\frac{X_1 + ... + X_n}{n}}$, and explain why Q is a pivot.

It's been quite sometime i had my probability and statistics course, so i'm really lost and don't know where to begin with this.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Did you mean $n=9$, so that $\overline X$ is the sample mean for fixed sample size $9$?

Comment: The paper doesn't specify that n = 9, but even though it doesn't i do think that is the case. I myself assumed that $n = 9$, which would make $\bar{X}$ the sample mean for $X_1, X_2,...,X_9$

Comment: Giving that paper a citation (author, title, etc.) in your Question would improve it by adding *context*.

Comment: It's not a paper like that. The questions were made by the professor i had in that course and it was our exam paper. Not to mention the paper isn't in english and it's only available for the students that took that exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X_i$ are normal, so are $\bar{X}_n$ and $Q$. We then just have to characterize their means and variances. We have ($n = 9$):

$$
\mathbb{E}(\bar{X}_n) = \frac{1}{9} \sum_i \mathbb{E}(X_i) = 4 \theta, \quad \text{Var}(\bar{X}_n) = \frac{1}{81}\text{Var}(X_i) = \frac{\theta^2}{9}
$$

Hence we get

$$
\mathbb{E}(Q) = \frac{3 \; \mathbb{E}(\bar{X}_n)}{\theta} -12 = 0, \quad \text{Var}(Q) = \frac{9}{\theta^2}\text{Var}(\bar{X}_n) = 1
$$

---

Proof of Variance

- Fact1: $\text{Var}(aX+b) = a^2 \text{Var}(X)$, i.e. the constants can be omitted from the computation and the variance is a quadratic operator
- Fact2: from Fact1 we then have $\text{Var}(3/\theta\bar{X}_n-12) = (3/\theta)^2 \text{Var}(\bar{X}_n)=(9/\theta^2) (\theta^2/9) = 1$

---

Therefore $Q \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Since its distribution does not depend on unknown parameters, it is a pivotal quantity

Comment: Okay, the part where you find their means makes sense and it's also the correct answer, but i'm unsure about the part where you find their variances. The variance for a Gaussian distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2 )$ is $Var(X) = \sigma$ and we got a N(4\theta, \theta^2). Why do we then get $\frac{\theta^2}{9}$ and swap it around for $Var(Q)$ so that it becomes $\frac{9}{\theta^2}$

Comment: @Mohammed I edited my answer. hope it's clearer now

Comment: okay it makes sense now, thanks for the help!